# Loop trought Content Controls Checkbox inside different tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have document with multiple tables in it(as seen in the attached image), so I try to verify only the field with the status  in the column "complete", those that are not selected (False)to work in it and continue reviewing one by one. So far my main problem is to retrieve the value from those specific content controls on those cells because I haven,t found the method/function to do it.

[image: Table 1 of n]

So my VBA code so far (and wrong btw) is this, any scope in how to retrieve a value of content control in a selected cell inside... (I fell like inception jk an element inside an element inside another element, we need to go deeper...)

```
Public Sub VerifyCheckBox()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastCC As Long, totalRows As Long, nRow As Long
Dim test1 As String
Dim nTbl As Table
Dim thisCell As Range

'lastCC = ActiveDocument.Content.ContentControls.Count
'test1 = ActiveDocument.Content.ContentControls(1).Type = wdContentControlCheckBox
'MsgBox "Found  " & lastCC & "  Content Controls  " & "  First checkbox...  " & test1

For Each nTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables 'Loop Trough the tables in the document
    If nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range = "Complete" Then

        totalRows = nTbl.Rows.Count 'Total number of rows in the selected table

        For nRow = 3 To totalRows
            If nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Content.ContentControl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox And nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Content.ContentControl.Checked = False Then
                thisCell = nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range.Select
                MsgBox "Review element:  " & nTbl.Cell(nRow, 1).Range & nTbl.Cell(nRow, 2).Range
            End If
        Next nRow

    End If
    'Debug.Print nTbl.Columns.Count & " " & nTbl.Rows.Count
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks so much in advance for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zegad, you were very close. Below you find your code improved including some comments and explanations.

```
Public Sub VerifyCheckBox()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastCC As Long, totalRows As Long, nRow As Long
Dim test1 As String
Dim nTbl As Table
Dim thisCell As Range

For Each nTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables 'Loop Trough the tables in the document

        totalRows = nTbl.Rows.Count 'Total number of rows in the selected table

        'why do you start as of four if your headers are 2nd and data start as of 3rd?
        For nRow = 3 To totalRows
            'you don't need this if you have 'complete' column as a third one
            'you would need something similar if 'complete' could be in different column
            'If nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range = "Complete" Then
        'NEW! let's check first if there is any ContentControl in cell    
        If nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range.ContentControls.Count > 0 Then
            'I assume that you have only one ContentControl per cell
            If nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range.ContentControls(1).Type = wdContentControlCheckBox _
                    And nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked = False Then
                    'if you want to select do it in this way
                    Set thisCell = nTbl.Cell(nRow, 3).Range
                    thisCell.Select
                MsgBox "Review element:  " & nTbl.Cell(nRow, 1).Range & nTbl.Cell(nRow, 2).Range
            End If
            End If
            'End If
        Next nRow


Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works great until the next element in the loop, and shows _"run time error '5941' the requested member of the collection does not exist"_ the debugger points to the IF conditional statement, any ideas

Comment: @Zegad, you right, I assumed that there is ContentControl in each cell in column 3. So, I made some imporvments- see in my answer.

Comment: Works great! I will try to improve it to different layouts (as empty cells at the end or merged cells)